# Добавление элементов в список словаря с одинаковыми ключами

Tags: c#, словари

Есть список вида

```
 List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
 people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Том", Id = "Id_1" });
 people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Том", Id = "Id_2" });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Ипполит", Id = "Id_3" });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Евкакий", Id = "Id_4" });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Евкакий", Id = "Id_5" });
```

То есть имена могут повторяться, а Id - нет.
Хочу создать словарь типа `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, чтобы у ключа был список из Id-шников. Как это можно сделать?
То есть Том:[Id_1, Id_2], Ипполит:[Id_3], Евкакий:[Id_4, Id_5]
Пробую вот так, но записывается только первый элемент

```
            foreach (var eee in people)
        {
            var key = eee.Name;
            if (!dictionaryElement.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                dictionaryElement[key] = new List<Id>();
                dictionaryElement[key].Add(eee.Id);
            }
        }
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!dictionaryElement.ContainsKey(key))
    dictionaryElement[key] = new List<Id>();
dictionaryElement[key].Add(eee.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, string> peopleDic1
                                    = people.GroupBy(p => p.Name)
                                            .Select(g => new
                                            {
                                                Name = g.Key,
                                                Ids = people
                                                            .Where(p => p.Name == g.Key)
                                                            .Aggregate(String.Empty,
                                                                       (a, n) => a + ", " + n.Id)
                                            })
                                            .ToDictionary(n => n.Name, n => n.Ids.Remove(0, 2));

Dictionary<string, List<string>> peopleDic2
                                    = people.GroupBy(p => p.Name)
                                            .Select(g => new
                                            {
                                                Name = g.Key,
                                                Ids = people
                                                        .Where(p => p.Name == g.Key)
                                                        .Aggregate(new List<string>(),
                                                                   (acc, p) => { acc.Add(p.Id); return acc; })
                                            })
                                            .ToDictionary(n => n.Name, n => n.Ids);
```